# WIndow Service onStart() can't invoke another meathod in which mongoDB distinct query result expected

Tags: c#, .net, json, mongodb, windows-services

I'm working on a function which need to run every hour and i adopted service way to write. but now i'm facing issues in running service while in debug mode help.
every thing looks fine to me, code start from debug section and calculation started but here is the problem when i try to get the distinct elements from db the service code stops.

```
//main
            static class Program
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// The main entry point for the application.
                /// </summary>
                static void Main()
                {
        #if DEBUG

                    Service1 myService = new Service1();
                    myService.onDebug();

        #else
                    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                    { 
                        new Service1() 
                    };
                    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #endif
                }
            }


            //*********************************************************

            //Service.cs code is here


            public Service1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    public void onDebug()
                    {
                        OnStart(null); //untill now working fine
                    }

                    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
                    {
                        try
                        {
        //this is the function i want to run every hour, i have made successfully perfect in a console application but in window service its not working

                            var hourlyTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(e => hourlyCalculateSummaryForAllDevices(), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0));
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string msg = ex.Message;
                        }
                        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ServiceStarted.txt");

                    }

                    protected override void OnStop()
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "HourlySummaryServiceStopped.txt");
                    }
                    //*********************************************************
                    //hourly Summary calculation functions
                    public static void hourlyCalculateSummaryForAllDevices()
                    {
                        findDistinctAssets(); //ok f11 pressed when cursor come here
                    }

                    static async void findDistinctAssets()
                    {
                        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(telemetryCollectionName);
                        var filter = new BsonDocument();
                        var cursor = await collection.DistinctAsync<Int64>("AssetName", filter);
                        //while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync()) //here the service code stopped automatically, im stuck why?
                        //{
                            var assets = cursor.Current;
                            foreach (var asset in assets)
                            {
                                CalculateSummaryOfAssets(Convert.ToInt64(asset));
                            }

                            Console.Read();
                        //}
                    }
```

Comment: windows service has no GUI. So `Console.Read();` will stop the service and will not continue.

Comment: Thanks but i have removed console.read() from there and it still stops running while executing
static async void findDistinctAssets()
                {
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(telemetryCollectionName);

 var filter = new BsonDocument();

var cursor = await collection.DistinctAsync<Int64>("AssetName", filter);
.
.
though i have successfully running this code on console application